# Make UiView sub class but background color show black color

Tags: iphone

I have taken a UiView subclass but it's background color is not changing

This class I am using these method

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 80, 200, 200)];
   if (self)
       {
       // Initialization code
       }
   return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   [[UIColor darkGrayColor]setFill];     
   CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
   CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

   CGContextBeginPath(context);
   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor);
   CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 1, 1);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100);
   CGContextStrokePath(context); // and draw 
}
```

I am calling this class to main view controller

```
Newclass *obj =[[Newsclass alloc]init]; 
obj.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
[self.view addsubview :obj];
```

but background color by default show black color. It is not changing

if i implemented background-color code   init with frame method or

draw rect method   than not changing.

if i code it

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
```

than it's method not called 
please suggest me UIview subclass black background color how to change

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should do the color part in UIView file.

```
if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220,60, 100, 300)])
{
    self.backgroundColor =[UIColor greenColor];
}
```

how ever you don't need to do in this case... ;)

it will definitely change your background color. But what happens next is that Draw rect method is called ,your color is no more visible as the draw rect method draws a view above it (whatever you draw in that method).

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

   CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0,0,200,300);

   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

   CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
}
```

You just cannot directly set the background color of cgcontext, you have to fill that context with color.
please make sure that you replace rectangle by rectangular frame of your view. It works like a charm for me.